# Use AJAX call to update a php session variable

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP script that reads PDF files in a specified folder. I have each file split by page. I have stored these file names in an array and have created an index variable called **`$count`**. There are left (page down) and right (page up) arrows. I need **`$count`** to increment on page down and decrement on page up.  I know I need to use AJAX to do this, but the only data I have to send is the *onclick* event.

Comment: You should add some code so it is possible to help you. For example in how you want your program to react.

Comment: Tightened wording.

Answer (score 0):

Perform an ajax request sending your action as a parameter :

```
JQuery.ajax({
    url: 'my_script.php?action=increment'
});
```

Then in my_script.php, update your session variable according to the parameter action.

I used jQuery for my example but any other library will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `$.ajax()` function is used to perform an asynchronous HTTP request.
here is a demo code to interact with php file

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'contact_form.php',
            data:'details='+Message,
            success:function(msg){
    $('#show-msg').html('<span >'+msg+'</span>');   
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event should be enough to send.
Technicly you just need to send to your server what button has been pressed and from there your variable in your session will go down or up according to whats the php logic receiving the ajax call.

So just make a simple php page that does something like this

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['Down']))
    $count --;
if(isset($_REQUEST['Up']))
    $count ++;
```

And on your page were you actually click the buttons
Just have a regular ajax call like so,

```
$("#UpButton").click(function(){
    $.post('linkToYourPage.php',{Up:true});
});
$("#DownButton").click(function(){
    $.post('linkToYourPage.php',{Down:true});
});
```